# Query process CPU % usage of multiple processes using single perf counter

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I could find multiple questions (and answers) about how to query the CPU usage of a particular process on SO and other sites, but I can't find any information about how to query multiple processes at the same time.

From what I gathered, the `PerformanceCounter` class does not allow either wildcards or an array of processes to be specified, so it seems to me that the only way of querying multiple processes is to create one `PerformanceCounter` instance per process.

The problem with that approach is that we need two `NextValue()` calls with a sleep interval in between them, so without the use of async code this process will take a total time of `<sleepTime> * <numberProcesses>` to complete, not quite making it feasible.

So the question is... is there a way of using a single `PerformanceCounter` instance to query multiple processes (at the same time)?

Comment: PerformanceCounter corresponds to a single counter instance, just as a `File` object corresponds to a single file. The folder equivalent is the `PerformanceCategory`, although the API is a bit cumbersome - you have to know the instance names, or use `GetInstanceNames()` with a LINQ filter to get at the actual instance names.

Comment: Reading values isn't expensive. How many processes are you trying to measure?

Comment: The problem is not whether it's expensive or not, it's that unless all reads are done at the same time, the values will be inaccurate. I'm trying to read about 20 processes.

Comment: If you want such accuracy, you should be looking at a profiler, not performance counters. The counters are published by the *processes*, they aren't stored in some central database.  No matter how fast you query them, by the time you query the 20th, the 1st will be different. That's why the API allows you to get all counters of a single instance, but not the same counter for all instances.

Comment: You could use WMI to perform a query that will return all values at once, but the OS still has to ask each process for the value.

Comment: Perf counters are fast because they consume no resources until someone actually tries to read them, eg Performance Monitor or another diagnostic application. That means that the reader has to go and ask each instance though, the value isn't stored anywhere in the meantime

Comment: Why not *reverse* this? Start a log in perfmon that stores the counters you want for a specific period?

Comment: I think using WMI might be a better option, also because in WMI I can filter on the query itself (as oppose to first querying every process and then filtering out the results I don't want). Anyway, just a bit odd that you can't do this using PerformanceCounters..